# MOUSE HOVERING IN SSRS REPORT TO CHANGE THE COLOR

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SSRS report. In that I am using a TEXT BOX for heading. Generally I am using GREEN color for the TEXT BOX. But I need to change it to RED when mouse hovers on it. Is it possible in SSRS.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with SSRS

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. But I have seen online that we can use CSS or HTML in text box. When i tried this the content is appearing in the output but not the effects. Anyhow I really appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a complete list of tags that will render as HTML when defined as placeholder text:

```
Hyperlinks: <A HREF>

Fonts: <FONT>

Header, style and block elements: <H{n}>, <DIV>, <SPAN>,<P>, <DIV>, <LI>, <HN>

Text format: <B>, <I>, <U>, <S>

List handling: <OL>, <UL>, <LI>`
```

Any other HTML markup tags will be ignored

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/importing-html-into-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017